# C# Uploading Video to Youtube without prompting user login: Youtube API V3

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, youtube

This is written in ASP.NET and C#
All is functioning properly just want to implement what's described below.

I have a program that is capable of uploading a video to YouTube with the account associated with the ClientID and ClientSecret.  The only issue with this is the fact that when my GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker goes through it prompts the user to login.  I want to make it so all users of this program or site are capable of uploading to that specific YouTube account without being asked for the username and password of that YouTube account.  Is there a way to make this possible?

This is the code that prompts the user login.  Can you initialize the account's login prior to this?  Without the user being required to do it?

```
        UserCredential credential;
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
            // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
            // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Google won't give the access token until the user gives the application permission through the prompt at least once. After that you should receive access when you make the call, as Google's user API will know permission has already been given. This is an intended feature to prevent malware from getting access to a user's YouTube/Google account.